# Display a widget into a modal dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a Angular.js site that has a large number of widgets. *In this case a widget is a template.html and a controller.js set up as an angular module.*

These widgets are being used on a dashboard where users can move them around, widgets may also need to appear in a modal popup and other tools may integrate with us by pulling the widgets into their tool.

Currently there are 26 modals and counting.

How can I create a modal dynamically so that I don't have to include the modals into each page?

Is there some way to make them global? Also I need to "load" a widget (template and controller) into the module because all modules will have the same structure, but may need a customized header, body and footer.

Normally I would have turned the widgets into directives but I'm working on a team who already has the widgets working on the dashboard.

P.S. We are using the $stateProvider and Angular-UI Bootstrap modals.

Comment: Sounds like you would want to create a global service for this.

Comment: That is a great idea @ajmajmajma - I'm going to need a service for sure. I just need to figure out how to load another template and controller into the modal.

Comment: I just did something similar in a project, posted in an answer below. The only thing i didn't do was bring a custom template and controller with it, but it shouldn't be too hard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to set up a service to do this for you globally, where you would pass whatever you needed to the modal for it to work so something like this -

```
.service(metadata.componentName, [
        '$modal',
        '$q',
        function($modal, $q) {
            return {
                confirm: function confirmModal(options) {
                    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        $modal.open({
                            size: 'sm',
                            template: '<div class="modal-body">' + options.message + '</div><div class="modal-footer"><button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button></div>',
                            controller: modalCtrlRJS.componentName
                        }).result.then(resolve, reject);
                    });
                },
                info: function infomModal(options) {
                    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        $modal.open({
                            size: 'sm',
                            template: '<div class="modal-body"> <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="ok()"><span>×</span></button>' + options.message + '</div>',
                            controller: timeoutModalCtrlRJS.componentName
                        }).result.then(resolve, reject);
                    });
                },
                error: function errormModal(options) {
                    return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
                        $modal.open({
                            size: 'sm',
                            template: '<div class="modal-body"> <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="ok()"><span>×</span></button>' + options.message + '</div>',
                            controller: timeoutModalCtrlRJS.componentName
                        }).result.then(resolve, reject);
                    });
                }
            };
        }
```

So these are simple modals, the trick here is you would probably use `templateUrl` not template, and pass in your own controllers. I am passing controllers here using requirejs syntax. Something like this should do the trick for you, then you would just call `yourService.whateverModal` and pass whatever params you need. You could pass whatever extra settings you need on the bootstrap-ui modal in that service call too, just depends how much you need to customize it.

Just 1 additional comment - I have wrapped these in `$q` so you have the option of using the promise when you call this modal service. For example - I used this to fire different events when the model gets closed or canceled.